# Android Touch Problems

Tags: android, touch, ontouchlistener

i have a SurfaceView and i want to recognize the MotionEvent Action_Up, but only the Action_Down event is triggered. Also i want to recognize another touch, while the first finger is still on the screen, but the OnTouch Event isnt triggered again.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
    int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
    if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        //blabla
    } else /* if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) */{
        //blabla
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
    if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        //blabla
    } else /* if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) */{
        //blabla
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

The pointerCount is always 1, no matter how many fingers are on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You must return true for an `ACTION_DOWN` event in your `OnTouchListener` if you are interested in being notified of the remaining events associated with that touch (`ACTION_MOVE`, `ACTION_UP`, etc.)

I would also recommend EITHER monitoring the touches using a listener OR in the `onTouchEvent` method of the view...not both.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Try capturing the getAction in a variable instead of calling it multiple times in your onTouch. Also make sure you're letting the listener know when the action is consumed.

```
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final int action = event.getAction();
            boolean consumed = false;
            switch(action){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    //down stuff logic
                            consumed = true;
                    break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    //up stuff logic
                            consumed = true;
                    break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    //move stuff logic
                            consumed = true;
                    break;
            }
            return consumed;
    }
```

As for number of fingers on the screen, remember multitouch support started at API level 5, so depending on your phone/minSDK you might not have it.